# split string for a range of columns Pandas

Tags: pandas

How can I split the string to list for each column for the following Pandas dataframe with many columns?

```
col1           col2
0/1:9,12:21:99 0/1:9,12:22:99
0/1:9,12:23:99 0/1:9,15:24:99
```

Desired output:

```
col1               col2
[0/1,[9,12],21,99] [0/1,[9,12],22,99]
[0/1,[9,12],23,99] [0/1,[9,15],24,99]
```

I could do:

```
df['col1'].str.split(":", n = -1, expand = True)
df['col2'].str.split(":", n = -1, expand = True)
```

but I have many columns, I was wondering if I could do it in a more automated way?

I would then like to calculate the mean of the 2nd element of each list for every row, that is for the first row, get the mean of 21 and 22 and for the second row, get the mean of 23 and 24.

Comment: What's the logic here?

Comment: looks like `for column in lst_of_columns: df[column] = df[column].str.split(':')`. But I really recommend against columns of lists.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for your reply. I see. I need to calculate an average for one of the numbers in the list. If not creating columns of list, what's a better way of solving this problem?

Comment: What exactly would `0/1` be in your output?

Comment: Which number you are interested in? You should mention that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is like your sample, you can make use of `stack`:

```
new_df = (df.iloc[:,0:2]
            .stack()
            .str.split(':',expand=True)
         )
```

Then `new_df` is double indexed:

```
          0     1   2   3
0 col1  0/1  9,12  21  99
  col2  0/1  9,12  22  99
1 col1  0/1  9,12  23  99
  col2  0/1  9,15  24  99
```

And say if you want the mean of 2nd numbers:

```
new_df[2].unstack(level=-1).astype(float).mean(axis=1)
```

gives:

```
0    21.5
1    23.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I think you first wrote it but if I want to get the average now for col1 and col2 separately, how could I achieve that? That is col1 = (21+23)/2 and for col2 = (22+24)/2?

Comment: remove `axis=1` in `mean()` gives you mean along columns.